# How to solve this in less than O(N)?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I have an array of sorted (ascending order) elements as input. I want to find out whether these elements make a series in which each current element is divisible by all the elements that came before it.
This is an obvious solution to this problem in O(n) time that I could think of:

```
bool CheckArray(int arr[], int no_of_elements)
{
    if (no_of_elements == 1)
        return true;

    for (int i = 1; i < no_of_elements; i++)
        if (arr[i] % arr[i - 1] != 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Example 1: Input: 3 6 9 12 Output: False

Example 2: Input: 3 6 12 Output: True

Is there any way to do it in less than O(n) time though? If yes, how?

Comment: If you have to check all elements at least once, you cannot do better than O(N)

Comment: Well in theory, you could split your array in two and do the check in parallel, then just check the elements on the edge of where the split happens. It is still O(n) but you can do more work in less time.

Comment: @Vallerious to be precise, cpu time would be the same, actually rather more

Comment: @Vallerious on a second thought on average I would expect this to be more expensive, because if there is a mismatch in eg the second element of one part then you either need an mechanism to stop the other parts (expensive) or you waste the effort of checking the other parts till the end (expensive too)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Stopping the process would mean signalling all threads to stop work. I agree that it might be an overkill.
So I guess you could do really small code changes that might be redundant because of fancy compilers, but you could traverse from end to 0 so that you compare to 0 which is cheaper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly you need an O(N) traversal in order to yield `true`.

The optimisation you can make is to yield a `false` as soon as possible.

I conject (and think the proof would be hard but is true if the numbers are arithmetically distributed) that adjacent larger number pairs (*a*, *b*) are less likely to be of the form (*a*, *na*) for integral *n* than smaller numbers. Therefore you could yield a `false` more quickly by considering the larger numbers first. In other words, running the loop from the last to the first element may well end up being statistically quicker. You'd have to profile on the typical number series that are presented to your function.

By the way, your preamble

```
if (no_of_elements == 1)
    return true;
```

is redundant.

Comment: OP already returns as soon as possible, the rest is really clever

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to do it in better than O(n).

Each element could have a value that changes the solution from true to false. So, you need to do at least an operation on each element, to check it.

As such you'll have at least O(n).